# Coalition Honor Guard and Hexproof

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As [Coalition Honor Guard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coalition%20Honor%20Guard) was card of the day on [DailyMTG](http://magic.wizards.com/en/node/314795) the other day, it got me thinking. If you gave it hexproof, through whatever means you choose e.g. [Swiftfoot Boots](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swiftfoot%20Boots), would my opponent be unable to play spells that target a single creature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your opponent can still cast spells.  As the last part of Coalition Honor Guard's text says (emphasis mine):

> your opponents must choose at least one Flagbearer on the battlefield
>   **if able.**

If they can't target a flagbearer (because of, say hexproof or a restriction on the spell, ie. "target green creature" and all flagbearers are white), you don't have to obey the rest of that text.